# MySQL returns always Error

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a check for max letters. If the check is not true the first time, its working. But if i have a insert with 200 characters or more it always returns `Message cant have more than 200 characters.` Even with 10 characters after the test return error. Can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
$stripped = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
$aktiv = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aktiv']);

if (isset($_POST['sendmsg'])) {
  if ($_POST['message'] < 200) {        
    echo "Message can't be more than 200 characters";
  } else {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE cms_prosjekt SET message = '$message',  active_msg = '$aktiv' WHERE id = $stripped;");

    header('Location: Location: /index.php?url=projectedit&id='.$stripped.'&code='.$id.'');
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably want `strlen($_POST['message'])` or `mb_strlen($_POST['message'])`. And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: shouldn't it be something like `strlen( $_POST['message'] )` inside the `if`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not mysql error but your php validation error

1) More than 200 is `>200` not `<200`

2) You need to check length of text not text

```
if (strlen($_POST['message']) > 200)
{       

     echo "Message can't be more than 200 characters";

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but If I insert more than 200 the error message comes up of course, but If i do a correct insert after this, the error message still stands. 
@nospor

Comment: It was my header redirect that mad the error stay. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Noman please do not edit post if you are not checked OP code earlier. Checking if form was submitted is few line above in OP code

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `($_POST['message'] < 200)` you should do it `(strlen($_POST['message']) > 200)`

At least that is the message that you display when the message is longer than 200.